# why cv2.destroyAllWindows don't work in if structure?

Tags: python, image, processing, opencv

I want to destroy all windows in python by cv2.destroyAllWindows().this is working by flowint 5 cv2.wiatKey() but when I use cv2.destroyAllWindows() in if structure it wont work...

this is the first code that can destroy widows:
       import cv2
       import numpy as np

```
   img = cv2.imread('test.png',-1)
   cv2.namedWindow('image',cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
   cv2.imshow('image',img)
   cv2.imwrite('image.png',img)
   k = cv2.waitKey(0)
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
   for i in range(5):    # maybe 5 or more
   cv2.waitKey(1)
```

this is the second code that can't destroy widows:
       import cv2
       import numpy as np

```
   img = cv2.imread('test.png',-1)
   cv2.namedWindow('image',cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
   cv2.imshow('image',img)
   cv2.imwrite('image.png',img)
   k = cv2.waitKey(0)

if k == 27 :
      cv2.destroyAllWindows()
      for i in range(10):    # maybe 5 or more
          cv2.waitKey(1)
elif k == ord('s') :
      cv2.imwrite('image.png',img)
      cv2.destroyAllWindows()
      for i in range(10):    # maybe 5 or more
          cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Are you absolutely certain the relevant section of your code is being executed?

Comment: Hi.thansk for your respect.yes,i test it today butt he result is the same...

Comment: That honestly doesn't answer my question. It would perhaps be good if you output the value of k before the if statement.

Comment: I check. when I press Esc K is 1048603 !!!! why ?

Comment: @MohammadJavadPasslar There are some additional flags included in the return value. Just simply mask the upper bits out (`k & 0xFF`). There are multiple questions about this on SO, just search around for the details.